# Why does the TypeScript compiler swear on the absence of a class property, if this property exists in it?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why does the TypeScript compiler swear on the absence of a class property, if this property exists in it?

> Property 'path' does not exist on type 'TutorService'.

```
this.tutorServiceService.getTutorServices()
      .then(tutorServices => {
        tutorServices.find(s => `/service/${s.path}` == this.router.url) // Property 'path' does not exist on type 'TutorService'.
      });
```

This is where the method  getTutorServices() is taken from:

```
getTutorServices(): Promise<TutorService[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json().data as TutorService[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And the problem class itself:

```
export class TutorService {
    id: number;
  title: string;
  menuTitle: string;
  sinosis: string;
  text: string;
  path: string; 
}
```

Comment: this might not be it, but if you should use an interface instead of a class for TutorService.

Comment: other than that it looks good. are you sure there's nothing else to cause it?

Comment: It's strange. I rebooted Webpack (or rather the Angulyar compiler2 - ng) and the error no longer disturbs. How so ??

Comment: I don't know.. some cached files somewhere maybe? Your code looks fine, apart from the interface thing. :)